# For loop and conditional statement to calculate a value

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Trying to Calculate a value for the Interest variable using the conditions i set below, but having trouble as it is returning 0, or if i rearrange the for loop it returns 6471 for each account. Would be great if you can help me fix the for loop so that the correct interest is shown in the console

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

int AccountNumber[8] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };

float Balance[8] = { 4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0, 7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44 };

int DaysSinceDebited[8] = { 20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45 };
int interest = 0;

//add your code here



cout << "Account Number\t" << "Balance\t\t" << "Days\t" << "Interest\t" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)

    cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (Balance[i] > 10000 || DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30)
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.06);
    else
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.03);



system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

here is my modification:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

int AccountNumber[8] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };

float Balance[8] = { 4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0, 7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44 };

int DaysSinceDebited[8] = { 20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45 };
int interest = 0;

//add your code here


for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (Balance[i] > 10000 || DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30)
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.06);
    else
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.03);

cout << "Account Number\t" << "Balance\t\t" << "Days\t" << "Interest\t" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)

    cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;





system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You seem to be printing the interest before you calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (Balance[i] > 10000 || DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30)
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.06);
    else
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.03);
    cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Account Number  Balance         Days    Interest
1001            4254.4          20      127
7940            27006.2         35      1620
4382            123.5           2       3
2651            85326.9         14      5119
3020            657             5       19
7168            7423.34         360     445
6245            4.99            1       0
9342            107864          45      6471
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int interest = 0;
```

Your code first sets the `interest` variable to 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;
```

And the very next thing that happens, is that your code prints the value of the `interest` variable, for every account. Since `interest` is set to 0, you get the value 0 printed, as you've observed.

The next thing that happens in your code is a second loop, and inside the loop you calculate and set `interest` for every account. Which is nice, except that you already displayed the value of `interest`.

You need to display `interest` *after* it is calculated, not before.

Comment: Yes i thought this too. So i moved the for loop calculating the interest above the line that displays the interest but it gives me the results 6471 each time

Comment: can you add what you have modified?

Comment: @DanielH Your first *for* loop calculated the value of interest for all accounts. It doesn't print anything. You calculate "interest" for the first account. Then the second account. And so on. So, in the end, the value of the "interest" variable will be the value that gets calculated for the last account. Then, you run your second `for` loop; which prints this value, the same value, for all accounts. This is what your code was doing. It was nice for someone else to write your code for you, unfortunately I don't think you learned anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You should move

```
cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;
```

to the 2nd for loop. It prints the same result 6471 because you calculates all the values and re-emplace into an only variable called **interest** but you don't display it on each calculation iteration, then the 6471 is the last result given by the conditional for the last element into data vectors. Then, you should display interest in each iteration of **for loop**, just like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if (Balance[i] > 10000 || DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30)
            interest = (Balance[i] * 0.06);
        else
            interest = (Balance[i] * 0.03);
cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;
}
```

besides, **interest** must be **float**. I hope it helps you :D

Comment: that is right. Even thought there will be type conversion, the precision of the result will be lost when assigned to an int. Thanks.