# Using a function to return a value

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops

I have this code at the moment that works and calculates the interest of an account depending on the conditions set. However I now need to code a function called `CalcInterest()` which takes as its *only* parameter - an Account, - and return the Interest calculated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int AccountNumber[8] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };

    float Balance[8] = { 4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0, 7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44 };

    int DaysSinceDebited[8] = { 20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45 };
    int interest = 0;

    //add your code here

    cout << "Account Number\t" << "Balance\t\t" << "Days\t" << "Interest\t" << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (Balance[i] > 10000 || DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30)
            interest = (Balance[i] * 0.06);
        else
            interest = (Balance[i] * 0.03);

        cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I have attempted, The function isn't working but there are no errors

```
   #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;


 float CalcInterest(int AccountNum);



int main()

{



cout << "Account Number\t" << "Balance\t\t" << "Days\t" << "Interest\t" << endl;

float CalcInterest(int AccountNum);

system("pause");
return 0;
};



float CalcInterest(int AccountNum) {

int interest = 0;
float Balance[8] = { 4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0, 7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44 };
int DaysSinceDebited[8] = { 20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45 };
int AccountNumber[8] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };


for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
if (Balance[i] > 10000 || DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30)
return interest = (Balance[i] * 0.06);
else
return interest = (Balance[i] * 0.03);
cout << AccountNumber[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;
}





}
```

Comment: Based on this, and your previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249011/for-loop-and-conditional-statement-to-calculate-a-value - it looks to me like you're trying to implement a moderately-complex application (relatively speaking) without having sufficiently studied fundamentals of C++. It's good that you're trying to learn, but you should go back, spend more time learning C++ fundamentals, and try even simpler programs, before attempting to write code of this kind of complexity. This is not a very good way to learn C++.

Comment: "takes as its ONLY parameter an Account" -- Are you suppose to have an `Account` type? Your `CalcInterest` function currently takes an `int`. For example are you suppose to have a function: `float CalcInterest(const Account& account) { ... }`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this is the last question on a sample test ( 8 parts) so just trying compile a set of solutions to possible questions, this is the final one. managed 1-6 on my own, just needing a couple hits on last 2

Comment: "Define a function that takes only one parameter, an Account" that means the data in the arrays is going to be global! That is an utterly wrong approach! The less stuff is visible where it shouldn't be, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, a grave syntax error possibly caused by copy-and-paste of code:

```
int main()
{
    /* ... */
    float CalcInterest(int AccountNumber);
    /* ... */
};
```

If you (1) intend to *call* the function `CalcInterest()`, you write its name and then the actual parameters inside round parens like so:

```
CalcInterest(5);
```

If you however want to*declare* the function, the syntax is correct per se, but function declarations do not belong inside another functions (short of lambdas that are defined completely inside another block of code. Funny thing is, this compiles fine, as far as I understand, this way: *declare variable `CalcInterest` of type `float` and pass to its constructor a default constructed `int` called `AccountNumber`*. Am I right? The power of C++ syntax applied.

Your second error is this:

```
float CalcInterest(int AccountNumber) {
    /* ... */
    int AccountNumber[8] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };
    if (AccountNumber == 1001 /* ... */) { /* ... */ }
```

After you (re)declare `AccountNumber` as an array of `int` of length `8`, your `int AccountNumber` function parameter gets shadowed, hence the compiler thinks you want to compare `1001` to the array `int AccountNumber[8]`. Here goes the error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'float CalcInterest(int)':
main.cpp:21:24: error: declaration of 'int AccountNumber [8]' shadows a parameter
     int AccountNumber[8] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };
                        ^
main.cpp:33:30: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
         if (AccountNumber == 1001 || AccountNumber == 4382 || AccountNumber == 3020 || AccountNumber == 6245)
                              ^
```

Your third error, this time logical, are the returns inside the `for` loop. think about it, on the very first loop iteration the first `return` is going ot get executed, and nothing else inside the function will be run! Is that what you intend to do?

Finally, as far as I understand, you want to factor out the code in the for loop into a function right? Might be done like so:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void CalcInterest(int i);

int main()
{
    cout << "Account Number\t" << "Balance\t\t" << "Days\t" << "Interest\t" <<    endl;
    for (int account = 0; account < 8; account++) {
        CalcInterest(account);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};

void CalcInterest(int i) {
    static const float Balance[8] = { 4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0, 7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44 };
    static const int DaysSinceDebited[8] = { 20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45 };
    static const int AccountNumbers[8] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245, 9342 };
    int interest = 0;
    if (AccountNumbers[i] == 1001 || AccountNumbers[i] == 4382 || AccountNumbers[i] == 3020 || AccountNumbers[i] == 6245)
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.06);
    else
        interest = (Balance[i] * 0.03);
    cout << AccountNumbers[i] << "\t\t" << Balance[i] << "\t\t" << DaysSinceDebited[i] << "\t" << interest << "\t" << endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. I will study this indepth, thanks again.If you wouldn't mind could you alter this a little to meet this condition? This function will take as its ONLY parameter an Account, and return the Interest calculated as shown

Comment: Does this solve your problem, in the sense, "does it fulfill what you were intending to do"?

Comment: almost, it's just the limit to one parameter that i'm struggling with now

Comment: Done with the help of `static` arrays. You might declare them as *global* variables, that is, *outside* of the `main()` function, where they would be visible to any function in the source file that contains `main()`, but that's not the best thing to do. Instead, you can indeed declare them inside the function, but to avoid refiling them every time the function is called, I've declared them as `static`.

Answer (score 0):

my compiler (GCC 4.9.2) said your function `CalcInterest` has a parameter named `AccountNumber` and in this function you have an array named `AccountNumber` too, after i rename either one, no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The AccountNumber is int and you are trying to dereference in the function as 
AccountNumber[i]. You need to pass int array or int pointer.

Example:

```
float CalcInterest(int *)
```

When calling:

```
CalcInterest(AccountNumber)
```