# Is there any difference in performance to declare a large variable inside a function as `static`?

Tags: c++, c, static-members

Not sure if this has already been asked before. While answering [this very simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249551/using-a-function-to-return-a-value/35249806#35249806), I asked myself the following instead. Consider this:

```
void foo()
{
    int i{};
    const ReallyAnyType[] data = { item1, item2, item3,
        /* many items that may be potentially heavy to recreate, e.g. of class type */ };
    /* function code here... */
}
```

Now in theory, local variables are recreated every time control reaches function, right? I.e. look at `int i` above - it's going to be recreated on the stack for sure. What about the array above? Can a compiler be as smart as to optimize its creation to occur only once, or do I need a `static` modifier here anyway? What about if the array is not `const`? (OK, if it's not `const`, there probably i snot sense in creating it only once, since re-initialization to the default state may be required between calls due to modifications being made during function execution.)

Might sound like a basic question, but for some reason I still ponder. Also, ignore the "why would you want to do this" - this is just a language question,  not applied to a certain programming problem or design. I mean both C and C++ here. Should there be differences between the two regarding this question, please outline those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a two questions here, I think:

- *Can* a compiler optimize a non-`static` `const` object to be effectively `static` so that it is only created once; and
- Is it a reasonable expectation that a given compiler will do so.

I think the answer to the second question is "No", because I don't see the point of doing a huge amount of control flow analysis to save the programmer the trouble of typing the word `static`. However, I've often been surprised what optimizations people spend their time writing (as opposed to the optimizations which *I* think they should be working on :-) ). All the same, I would strongly recommend using the word `static` if that's what you wanted.

For the first question, there are circumstances under which the compiler could perform the optimization based on the "as-if" rule, but in very few cases would it work out.

First of all, if any object or subobject in the initializer has a non-trivial constructor/destructor, then the construction/destruction is visible, and this is not an example of copy elision. (This paragraph is C++ only, of course.)

The same would be true if any computation in the initializer list has visible side-effects.

And it should go without saying that if any subobject's value is not constant, the computation of that subobject would need to be done on each construction.

If the object and all subobjects are trivially copyable, all the initializer-list computations are constant, and the only construction cost is that of copying from a template into the object, then the compiler still couldn't perform the optimization if there is any chance that the addresses of more than one live instance of the object might be simultaneously visible. For example, if the function were recursive, and the object's address was used somewhere (hard to avoid for an array), then there would be the possibility that the addresses of two of these objects from different recursive invocations of the function might be compared. And they would have to compare unequal, since they are in fact separate objects. (And, now that I think of it, the function would not even need to be recursive in a multi-threaded environment.)

So the burden of proof for a compiler wishing to optimize that object into a single static instance is quite high. As I said, it may well be that a given compiler actually attempts to perform that task, but I definitely wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Great answer, takes some time to read! So, just to clarify, a `const` is no guarantee at all and I'm actually wrong in seeing it as almost identical to `const static` in this case? Guess it's some real confusion in my head.

Comment: @iksemyonov: `const` is just a promise to not change the value of the object. It doesn't even imply that two instances of the object are identical. `const int now[3] = {hour(), minute(), second()};`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler would almost certainly do whatever is deemed most optimal, but most likely it will have it in read-only memory and turn your local variable into a pointer that points to the array in read-only memory. This assumes your array is equivalent to a POD type (or a class composed of POD types; if your class does something non-trivial and/or modifies other things, there is no way the compiler can fairly do this optimization).

Comment: That with the `const` and without a `static`, right?

Comment: Yes, it would require the `const`. Without it, it's you describe - it would need to re-generate on each call due to possible local modification (unless perhaps the compiler can determine that *for sure* you are not modifying the non-const array).

Comment: @JimBuck However you have a class-type with side effects, then probably the object will be created at every loop iteration.

Comment: Yup, for sure, but I'm only addressing the example given in the OP.

Comment: Well, the code reads "e.g. of class type" so this is included for sure!

Comment: Ahh, ok, yeah, if it's a non-trivial class (such that, yeah, has side effects), then no, cannot put this in read-only memory. But if it's more of a trivial class, like say a class that deals with an RGBA color type, that can certainl go to read-only memory.)

Comment: Can't be put in read-only *even* when there is a `const` modifier? Or are we down the non-const branch of the discussion starting with comment #2?

Comment: It depends on how smart the compiler is and how "simple" the class is, but a const class that is pretty much equivalent to a POD type *should* be able to be put into read-only memory. But if you are really concerned as to whether it will do it for a particular platform you are working on, try your real-life example and see how it compiles.

Comment: OK, great, I was more at the "language-rule" level, but of course I will compile and test when a real need arises.

Comment: Some rule-quoter can do better than me, but my analysis is based on what I've seen in disassemblies and what I "know" a compiler can/should be able to do versus what it can't/shouldn't.